# Passing a wall when travelling at a very high speed

Tags: particle-physics

I want to know whether it is possible to escape through a wall or any solid obstacle while travelling at a very high speed,greater than speed of light.Is there any relation between speed,mass and wall force so that if someone achieved that ratio may escape the wall?

Comment: It's not possible (or necessary) to travel *faster* than the speed of light; see http://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know whether it is possible to escape through a wall or any solid obstacle while travelling at a very high speed,greater than speed of light.

The greater the speed you travel at, the more kinetic energy you gain. The more kinetic energy you have, the easier it will be to smash through a wall.

> Is there any relation between speed,mass and wall force so that if someone achieved that ratio may escape the wall?

Yes, if the energy necessary to break the wall is $E$ and the speed is $v$ and the mass is $m$ then you need $mv^2/2 \ge E$.

It isn't possible to go faster than the speed of light. See [this experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0BOpiMQXQA) where they try to accelerate electrons more and more, but cannot increase their speed beyond a limit.